# How to serialize a has_many_attached in Active Model Serializer using JSON API format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

As of right now, i have a model with a `has_one_attached :file` which i'm serializing with a method as follows.

```
# app/models/my_model.rb
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :file

  def file_url
    if file.attached?
      Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_url(file)
    end
  end
end
```

And then in my serializer with activemodel serializer( JSON API format)

```
type :my_model

attributes(
  :file_url
)
```

Which works just fine, now i'm moving to a has_many_attached :files, and i'm having problems serializing it. i've tried:

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :files
  
  def files_url
    files.each_With_object([]) do |file, array|
    array << Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_url(file)
  end
end
```

then in my app/controller/my_model_controller.rb

```
  def my_model_params
    params.require(:my_model).permit(:files => [])
  end
```

And finally, in my serializer, i just call :files_url(instead of file_url, as i used to, which worked with one file), but it won't work:

```
type :my_model

attributes(
  :files_url
)
```

Any idea on what am i missing? I can't seem to find much useful info regarding serializing has_many_attached. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! it actually works, i was just sending the wrong params to Insomnia.

I replaced `:files => []` in my_model_params with `files: []`. And in Insomnia i send each file in the `my_model[files][]` param.